# Why are some storage devices shown on 'Places' instead of the 'Devices' tab?

Tags: nautilus, devices

As the image shown below, the device "**54CF-068B**" is not where it's supposed to be.

Is this a bug or a feature of some sort?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Devices that have been bookmarked show under "Places" instead of "Devices".

Comment: The device isn't bookmarked. It's a fresh device.

Comment: Have you checked the file `~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks` to see if the device is listed there? BTW I updated the wording of my answer to be more accurate.

Comment: Yes. It's a new device. I have no bookmarks set on nautilus.